# How to start an invisible process in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to use system.diagnostics.process.start("Process.exe")
But the process would not be seen by the user?
For example, I want to play an audio in the background using windows media player, the audio will play but wmp won't be visible. Is it possible?

Comment: Invisible as in no foreground window, or Invisible as in nothing showing up in task manager?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("mplayer2.exe")
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

Process.Start(startInfo)
```

[ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle.aspx):

> The hidden window style. A window can
>   be either visible or hidden. The
>   system displays a hidden window by not
>   drawing it. If a window is hidden, it
>   is effectively disabled. A hidden
>   window can process messages from the
>   system or from other windows, but it
>   cannot process input from the user or
>   display output. Frequently, an
>   application may keep a new window
>   hidden while it customizes the
>   window's appearance, and then make the
>   window style Normal.

Comment: Note that, in some cases (I don't know which, `Me.VB.NETfu < Expert`) you may need to use `oStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True` as I did, because the above did not work. Perhaps because I'm redirecting StandardOutput?