# hide cmd in vb.net not working

Tags: vb.net, shell, command-line, cmd, hidden

I'm trying to hide cmd windows with vb.net without success.

```vb
Dim oProcess As New Process()
Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", " /c cscript ""%windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs"" /xpr | findstr ""The machine""")
oStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
oStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo
oProcess.Start()

Dim sOutput As String
Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardOutput
    sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()

End Using
TextBox4.Text = sOutput
```

any help please what is the mistake in my code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start an invisible process in vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048035/how-to-start-an-invisible-process-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the [**`CreateNoWindow` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow(v=vs.110).aspx) as well.

```vb
oStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
```

Also, this is just redundant:

```vb
oStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized '<-- Remove this line.
oStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
```

Setting `WindowStyle` to minimized won't affect anything since you change it to `Hidden` right after. When you use the `=` operator you ***replace*** a variable's or property's current value with a new one.

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck! :)